# 'LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glew32s.lib' '

Tags: c++, cmake, glew

the error occurs when running the following cmake config

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(vertex)

add_executable(vortex expositive.cpp)

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

add_subdirectory(plugins/glfw)

set( GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE )
set( GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE )
set( GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE )

set(glew_DIR C:/Users/Users/AppData/Local/nvim/plugins/plugins/glew/lib/Release/x64)

target_include_directories(vortex PUBLIC plugins/glfw/include)

target_include_directories(vortex PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/glew/include)

#target_compile_definitions(vortex PRIVATE GLEW_STATIC)

target_link_directories(vortex PUBLIC plugins/glfw/src PUBLIC plugins/glew/bin/Release/x64)

find_library(GLEW_LIBRARY NAMES glew32s PATH_SUFFIXES glew_DIR)

find_package(glm REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(vortex glew32s glfw glm::glm)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

if (OPENGL_FOUND)
    message("opengl found")
    message("include dir: ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    message("link libraries: ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY}")
else (OPENGL_FOUND)
    message("opengl not found")
endif()

target_link_libraries(vortex ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})
```

I've various alternatives in the suggested answers to similar questions(e.g using find_package directly), yet I doesn't resolve my error. I'm compiling using MSVC 2019.

When added to the target_link_directories, the lib's directory, the error was resolved in the expense of generating two warnings

```
(Link target) ->
  glew32s.lib(glew.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'glew_static.pdb' was not found with 'glew32s.lib(glew.obj)' or at 'C:\U
sers\Users\AppData\Local\nvim\plugins\plugins\Debug\glew_static.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\Users\AppData\Local\nvim\plugins\plugins\vortex.vcxproj]
  LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library [C:\Users\Users\AppData\Local\nvim\plugins\plugins\vortex.vcxproj]

    2 Warning(s)
```

Comment: Where is `glew32s.lib` is located? Add its directory to the list in `target_link_directories()`.

Comment: **Downgrade** from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76166331/cmake-errors-out-on-not-containing-required-symbols), are you sure? That time your have used the variable `GLEW_LIBRARY`, which you have obtained by `find_library()` call. Now your question resembles [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76157674/cmake-cannot-find-statically-linked-glew32-lib) with the same error message.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Expected a more productive response given your basement dweller-like recollection abilities. The same error message or its variation appears regardless if I invoke the variable as you should've already deduced judging by my initial sentence. And your link to my firstly posted question is no longer valid.

Comment: @273K I've edited the question, it generated two warnings.

Comment: @273K Removing the directory of the .dll from the target_link_directories quelled the warnings.

Comment: "The same error message or its variation appears regardless if I invoke the variable as you should've already deduced judging by my initial sentence." - What "initial sentence" you are talking about? If you mean "I've various alternatives in the suggested answers to similar questions", then it contains **no useful information**: neither what have you tried nor the outcome of that attempts. "And your link to my firstly posted question is no longer valid." - The link is valid. It can be viewed by you (as an author) and by other users with 10k+ reputation.

Comment: According to the edit of your question post, you have the **problematic** `glew32s.lib` file. But instead of asking specifically of that file and providing relevant error message (and other details), you prepare the code when the linker cannot find the library at all and ask about the "cannot open file" message. That way you only confuses the people who wanted to help you, because none of the solutions for that message doesn't solve your actual problem about the problematic library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The initial sentence in the context of my comment reply to you. Or in detail, the "downgrade" is irrelevant since the variable invocation or its lack thereof doesn't affect the outcome as shown in my previous question, in fact, it's the same. Sure, this irrelevance cannot be perceived by others without the context of the previous question which you provided, but I expected *you* as the provider to be aware.

Comment: "the variable invocation or its lack thereof doesn't affect the outcome" - Do you mean that the error message - `cannot open file 'glew32s.lib' ` - remains if you **replace** `glew32s` with `${GLEW_LIBRARY}` in the `target_link_libraries` call? I hardly can believe in that.